# How to add value in TimeSeries in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to add values in multiple time series, but failed

```
using TimeSeries
ta1 = TimeArray([Date(2015, 10, 01), Date(2015, 11, 01)], [15, 16])
ta2 = TimeArray([Date(2015, 11, 01), Date(2015, 12, 01)], [11, 3])
ta3 = TimeArray([Date(2015, 12, 01), Date(2016, 1, 01)], [1, 5])
# m12 = merge(+, ta1, ta2, ta3)
```

I expect the `m12` should equal to

```
m12 == TimeArray([Date(2015, 10, 01), Date(2015, 11, 01),
                  Date(2015, 12, 01), Date(2016, 1, 1)],
                 [15,27,4,5])
```

error message

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching merge(::typeof(+), ::TimeArray{Int64,1,Date,Array{Int64,1}}, ::TimeArray{Int64,1,Date,Array{Int64,1}}, ::TimeArray{Int64,1,Date,Array{Int64,1}})
Closest candidates are:
  merge(::TimeArray{T,N,D,A} where A<:AbstractArray{T,N} where D<:TimeType where N, ::TimeArray{T,N,D,A} where A<:AbstractArray{T,N} where D<:TimeType where N, ::TimeArray{T,N,D,A} where A<:AbstractArray{T,N} where D<:TimeType where N, ::TimeArray{T,N,D,A} where A<:AbstractArray{T,N} where D<:TimeType where N...; kw...) where T at /home/dlin/.julia/packages/TimeSeries/8Z5Is/src/combine.jl:78
  merge(::Function, ::AbstractDict, ::AbstractDict...) at abstractdict.jl:314
  merge(::NamedTuple, ::Any) at namedtuple.jl:264
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[5]:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way to easily do this within the `merge`/`vcat`/`map` machinery in `TimeSeries`, if you're okay with turning your series into a DataFrame I would probably just do that:

```
julia> df = join(DataFrame(ta1), DataFrame(ta2), DataFrame(ta3),  on = :timestamp, kind = :outer, makeunique=true)
4×4 DataFrame
│ Row │ timestamp  │ A       │ A_1     │ A_2     │
│     │ Date       │ Int64⍰  │ Int64⍰  │ Int64⍰  │
├─────┼────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 2015-10-01 │ 15      │ missing │ missing │
│ 2   │ 2015-11-01 │ 16      │ 11      │ missing │
│ 3   │ 2015-12-01 │ missing │ 3       │ 1       │
│ 4   │ 2016-01-01 │ missing │ missing │ 5       │

julia> df = coalesce.(df, 0)
4×4 DataFrame
│ Row │ timestamp  │ A     │ A_1   │ A_2   │
│     │ Date       │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼────────────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 2015-10-01 │ 15    │ 0     │ 0     │
│ 2   │ 2015-11-01 │ 16    │ 11    │ 0     │
│ 3   │ 2015-12-01 │ 0     │ 3     │ 1     │
│ 4   │ 2016-01-01 │ 0     │ 0     │ 5     │


julia> df.A += (df.A_1 .+ df.A_2)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 15
 27
  4
  5

julia> TimeArray(df.timestamp, df.A)
4×1 TimeArray{Int64,1,Date,Array{Int64,1}} 2015-10-01 to 2016-01-01
│            │ A     │
├────────────┼───────┤
│ 2015-10-01 │ 15    │
│ 2015-11-01 │ 27    │
│ 2015-12-01 │ 4     │
│ 2016-01-01 │ 5     │
```

Comment: Why my `df.A += (df.A_1 .+ df.A_2)` will return missing instead of the sum?

Comment: My apologies - I actually did `coalesce.(df, 0)` in between to replace `missing` with 0 - I updated the answer above.